# How to insert bookdown page into a hugo static website

Tags: hugo, bookdown

I am working on a blog driven by hugo. I want to insert a bookdown page into a hugo. For example, my domain is https://example.name. And I write a book by bookdown. I hope I can insert this bookdown page into the address like this  https:/example.name/notes/abc, so that if I open this link, it will direct into this bookdown page I made. How can I make it?

Answer (score 2):

The generated HTML from [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/) can be put in the Hugo static directory **/static/notes/abc** these files can than be accesses at **http://example.name/notes/abc/**.